# slice vs extract! rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-hash

I was making some reviews today to an old code and this arises, might be a silly question if so apologize in advance, but is there any real difference between slice and extract! functions (for hashes), I looked in the documentation and there is no obvious difference between them (at least for me):

- [`Hash#extract!`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/extract%21)
- [`Hash#slice`](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice)

Didn't found anything on the community either, thx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`slice`](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/hash#method-i-slice) method returns a *new Hash* containing the selected elements. This preserves the original object.

The [`extract!`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-extract-21) method *removes those entries from the original hash* and returns the extracted elements. This alters the original object.

> Note: In many cases Ruby methods ending in `!` alter the object they're called on as opposed to similar methods which do not have that extension where a new object is returned.

The difference requires a careful reading of the documentation where the `extract!` method is described as:

> Removes and returns the key/value pairs matching the given keys.

Where "removes" here is the differentiator.